# Is is possible to show XML attributes when using an external CSS style sheet?

Tags: css, xml, stylesheet

I'd like to display some XML in the browser, but add some custom color styling, etc., to certain attributes of tags.  I am able to get an essentially blank external sheet recognized:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="/css/testresult.css"?>
```

But this seems to have the effect of making the browser display the XML as if it were HTML, i.e. it only displays tag content text and not attributes.  Is there any way to get the "raw" XML display view, but with just a few tweaks to styling?

Using Firefox if that's relevant.

Comment: Erm... Put `<pre>` tags around it?  What about using Markdown or some other code formatter?

Comment: The <pre> won't allow formatting of the XML, which is the goal.  Does Markdown allow customization of formatting based on content? Or just generic XML formatting?

Comment: Markdown is what is used here on Stack Overflow.  The formatting is customized on a per-language basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have yet to see any indication it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, when Firefox displays XML files, it uses it's own parser, so I don't see how that could be influenced by your stylesheet, as the only function of the parser is to display XML in a readable way.

Maybe you can use XSLT you do what you need, but that would require some additional work.
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xsl.asp

Comment: Here's an example of stylesheet affecting rendering in Firefox: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/001/doc.xml

Comment: Thats not changing the colors in the default rendering.